# 'She had begun by saying' = 'She had begun to say'?

Tags: idioms

> "You should have a shop," she had begun by saying, loading Miss Bartlett's plate with scones and home-made ginger jam, "properly equipped and converted ..." [phrase ends after the direct speech]

I do not quite understand the clause 'she had begun by saying' here. Is it idiomatic and equivalent in meaning to 'she had begun to say', or is the object of 'begun' implicit (, or both)?

Answer (score 1):

*She had begun to say* and *She had begun by saying* have different meanings and connotations.

> *He/She had begun to say*

This construction normally indicates that the speaker started to say something that ended in an incomplete thought, either by way of distraction or by interruption.

***He had begun to say*** *he loved her, when she grabbed the bouquet of roses he brought for her and smacked him in the face with it.*

> *He/She had begun by saying*

This construction normally indicates that an action or chain of actions started with something that was said.

***She had begun by saying*** *that she was an upstanding citizen, and continued on to demonstrate it with statements about her donations to charity and involvement in the community.*

In the case of your example, the activity of loading the scones onto the plate started with the utterance "You should have a shop," and continued onto the plate becoming filled and subsequent conversation.